# Member lookup over generic constraint in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

I have this simple code : (simplified)

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var s1 = new Student();
            var s2 = new Student();
            myGenericClass<Student> Mgc = new myGenericClass<Student>();
            Mgc.Eq(s1,s2);
        }
    }

    class myGenericClass<T> where T : Person
    {
        public void Eq(T t1, T t2)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(t1.Equals(t2));
        }
    }

    class Person
    {
         public  bool Equals(Person p)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    class Student : Person
    {
         public bool Equals(Student obj)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

The invoked method is `Person's` and here is the question :

The `myGenericClass` is initialized with `Student` so T is Student. There is also a constraint there which is : `where T : Person` - which means Person [should be a base class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx). ( and Student do accomplish this)

Question :

1) Is the reason for this behavior relates to Generics ?

2) If so , why still Person's method is running and not Student ? What stopping it from dealing with Student ?

Edit , I also saw this [in the spec](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=btlM21ivisMC&pg=PA514&lpg=PA514&dq=%22If%20T%20is%20a%20type%20parameter,%20then%20the%20set%20is%20the%20union%20of%20the%20sets%20of%20accessible%22&source=bl&ots=2K27puxbz0&sig=YRGUYu8OMm2gxveoDrXfW8vcxS4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XJIuU6CmIcTN7AbQ_YHYBg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22If%20T%20is%20a%20type%20parameter,%20then%20the%20set%20is%20the%20union%20of%20the%20sets%20of%20accessible%22&f=false)

Comment: You need to explicitly override methods in C#, compared to how it works in Java.

Comment: @Zache Yes  , but it has nothing to do with the behavior I described above :-)

Comment: it has something to do with why it's calling the "wrong" method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "this behavior" you mean that it calls the method on `Person`, then no, this is normal OOP.

In order for your code to call "the correct" method depending on the actual `T` used, you need to make that method `virtual` in the base class, and then `override` it in descendants:

```
class Person
{
    public virtual bool Equals(Person p)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

class Student : Person
{
    public override bool Equals(Person obj)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

But observe something else as well, in order for `Equals` in `Student` to override the one in `Person`, it needs to take a `Person` parameter as well.

Note that generics doesn't mean "figure out which method to call at runtime", it's still the compiler that determines, at compile-time, which methods to call, and all it can see when compiling the generic class is the `Person` class, so it cannot determine anything about the potential usage of `Student`.

You can verify this behavior with this simple [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program:

```
void Main()
{
    Base o = new Derived();
    o.Test1();
    o.Test2();
}

public class Base
{
    public void Test1()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Base.Test1");
    }

    public virtual void Test2()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Base.Test2");
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public void Test1()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Derived.Test1");
    }

    public override void Test2()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Derived.Test2");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Base.Test1
Derived.Test2
```

as well as this warning (which you probably have in your code as well):

> Warning: 'UserQuery.Derived.Test1()' hides inherited member 'UserQuery.Base.Test1()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

Comment: No, it doesn't, this is as I said normal OOP. The compiler determines which method to call in both my example and your example, and it only sees `Person`, so it cannot use anything in `Student`.

Answer (score 0):

The `myGenericClass<T>.Eq` method has no knowledge of the classes that derive from `Person`; all that it knows is that `T` is a `Person` and that `Person` has a `Equals(Person p)` method. Since the method call is resolved at compile time, it's `Person.Equals(Person p)` that is called, regardless of more specific methods declared in derived types.

However you could do something like that:

```
class myGenericClass<T> where T : Person, IEquatable<T>
{
    public void Eq(T t1, T t2)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(t1.Equals(t2));
    }
}

class Person : IEquatable<Person>
{
    public  bool Equals(Person p)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

class Student : Person, IEquatable<Student>
{
    public  bool Equals(Student s)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

In this case, `myGenericClass<T>.Eq` will use the `Equals` method from `IEquatable<T>`, and will end up calling the `Student` implementation. However it requires that all classes that inherit from `Person` also implement `IEquatable<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you require you will need to add an interface like so:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var s1 = new Student();
  var s2 = new Student();
  myGenericClass<Student> Mgc = new myGenericClass<Student>();
  Mgc.Eq(s1, s2);

  var p1 = new Person();
  var p2 = new Person();
  myGenericClass<Person> Pgc = new myGenericClass<Person>();
  Pgc.Eq(p1, p2);
}

class myGenericClass<T> where T : IFoo<T>
{
   public void Eq(T t1, T t2)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(t1.Equals(t2));
   }
}

interface IFoo<T>
{
    bool Equals(T t);
}

class Person : IFoo<Person>
{
   public bool Equals(Person p)
   {
       return true;
   }
}

class Student : IFoo<Student>
{
    public bool Equals(Student obj)
   {
       return false;
   }
}
```

This will print `False` then `True`.

I hope this helps.